# Persistência com Spring e Thymeleaf em múltipla tabelas no mesmo form

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-jpa

Estou com outra visão

Como posso passar dois objetos no ModelAndView, de forma que ao chamar uma requisição para salvar consiga fazer essa distribuição de objetos para cada Entyti.

Tenho Entyti Cliente e Contato, na page preciso salvar os valores passados, sendo redistribuído conforme objeto mapeado no ModelAndView.

EX.

*{contato.email} - seria salvo no contato
 *{nome} - seria salvo no cliente;

Lembrando que estou usando Thymelealf no form.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode referenciar o objeto e o atributo diretamente no elemento do formulário ao invés de definir apenas um th:object para todo o form, por exemplo:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/cadastrar}">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="${contato.email}"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" th:field="${cliente.nome}"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Depois disso basta receber no método salvar do seu controller os dois objetos por parâmetro.